# INVALID_PARAMETER: The parameter provided does not correspond to any valid entity Terraform NewRelic

Tags: terraform, newrelic

I am receiving below error while pushing rules to new relic using terraform

```
INVALID_PARAMETER: The parameter provided does not correspond to any valid entity[0m

  with newrelic_notification_channel.cloudops,
  on main.tf line 300, in resource "newrelic_notification_channel" "PD_TEST":
 300: resource "newrelic_notification_channel" "PD_Channel"

Entities' types do not match
```

I am using below code:

```
resource "newrelic_notification_channel" "PD_Channel" {
    name = "pagerduty-channel-production"
    type = "PAGERDUTY_SERVICE_INTEGRATION"
    destination_id = "8dasd-asdad-adsadsa-xxxx"
    product = "IINT"
  
    property {
      key = "summary"
      value = "{{ annotations.title.[0] }}"
    }
  
    property {
      key   = "customDetails"
      value = <<-EOT
            {
              "id":{{json issueId}},
              "IssueURL":{{json issuePageUrl}},
              "NewRelic priority":{{json priority}},
              "Total Incidents":{{json totalIncidents}},
              "Impacted Entities":"{{#each entitiesData.names}}{{this}}{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}{{/each}}",
              "Runbook":"{{#each accumulations.runbookUrl}}{{this}}{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}{{/each}}",
              "Description":"{{#each annotations.description}}{{this}}{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}{{/each}}",
              "isCorrelated":{{json isCorrelated}},
              "Alert Policy Names":"{{#each accumulations.policyName}}{{this}}{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}{{/each}}",
              "Alert Condition Names":"{{#each accumulations.conditionName}}{{this}}{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}{{/each}}",
              "Workflow Name":{{json workflowName}}
            }
          EOT
    }
  }
```

I am pushing NR alerts using terraform and here I am trying to create Pagerduty details

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are trying to create this channel in relation to a destination who’s type is not PAGERDUTY_SERVICE_INTEGRATION

You can verify the destination type via nerdgraph